# @media screen doesn't work

Tags: css, media-queries

```
@media screen and (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 769px)
```

The code between this media query is taken even if the size of the window is 1920px !

Look at this code :

```
.row-contact{
    .col-xs-12:first-child {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 769px){
    .row-contact {
        padding: 0 !important;

        .col-xs-12:first-child {
            margin-top: 12%;
        }
    }
}
```

In full screen I have `margin-top: 12%`, however, it must be `margin-top: 0` !

Why this isn't working ?

**EDIT**
I found the solution ! 
I closed the media query before writing the SCSS instruction

Thanks for your help ! :D

Comment: You might want to show us the generated css as well? Maybe that could help to solve your problem

Comment: You code is working, See https://jsfiddle.net/wohe9daL/ Try resizing the panel to check!

Comment: Oh .. So I don't know why it doesn't work with my code ..

Comment: Maybe, you should post your html and your generated css?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.row-contact{
    .col-xs-12:first-child {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 769px){
    .row-contact {
        padding: 0 !important;
    }
     .col-xs-12:first-child {
          margin-top: 12%;
     }
}
```

Try this way because nesting is not working if you are not using `LESS` or `SCSS`

Answer (score 0):

I think you use nested css so that your code not work

```
    @media screen and (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 769px){
    .row-contact {
        padding: 0 !important;
    }
    .col-xs-12:first-child {
        margin-top: 12%;
    }
}
```

Try to use above code 
Thanks :)

Comment: If I use it, every .col-xs-12 will be touch, and I don't want this ^^